# JQuery File input element inconsistently fires in Chrome when wrapped in $timeout

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

So, I have a directive for handling file uploads, (wraps around angular-file-upload), and in some instances this directive wraps an anchor tag. This anchor tag's click event results in an `$apply` already being run when the directive runs the following code, where the `.fileUploadInput` element is an `<input type="file" />`:

```
fileUploadClick = (event: any) => {
  this.element.find('.fileUploadInput').click();
};
```

To solve this problem I wrapped it in `$timeout`:

```
fileUploadClick = (event: any) => {
  this.$timeout(() => {
    this.element.find('.fileUploadInput').click();
  });
};
```

In Chrome 43 (Not FF/Safari), the file picker requires multiple click events before opening the OS picker. I can see that the function call inside the timeout is run each time, but only intermittently will the OS picker actually open. Removing the `$timeout` will cause the picker to open every time, but will cause the `$apply` is already in progress error.

Does any one have any idea what would cause adding a timeout to cause this behavior in Chrome? Alternatively, is there any way to stop the existing `$apply` or a way to wait for it outside of `$timeout`? $interval causes the same problem.

Thanks,

Matt